# How to use php monolog

Tags: php, swiftmailer, monolog

I've heard a lot about monolog(https://github.com/Seldaek/monolog) & trying to use that in one of our app. But, can't able to fig. out how to use that. Don't know it's I'm only can't able to get any documentation of it or really it has no documentation at all.

We want to log all our errors in DB & as well as send an email notification about error when it'll get generate. For sending email we are using Swiftmailer(swiftmailer.org).

I can be able to run this sample code from Github link,

```
<?php
use Monolog\Logger;
use Monolog\Handler\StreamHandler;

// create a log channel
$log = new Logger('name');
$log->pushHandler(new StreamHandler('path/to/your.log', Logger::WARNING));

// add records to the log
$log->addWarning('Foo');
$log->addError('Bar');
```

but can't able to understand how to use this with DB & any other email library.

Comment: You have to use the different Handlers of Monolog. It offers already Handlers for Swiftmailer, MongoDB and CouchDB. I'm not sure, but I guess you have to create one for RDBMS yourself.

Comment: @SenseException : Yeah!!! that's i know. But, i can't able to fig. out how to use those handlers. There is no example at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You posted an example yourself. Instead of StreamHandler use one or more of the other handlers that monolog is offering.

You have to look into the code of the handlers to see which dependencies they need. Look inside the Monolog directory and you'll find the Handler classes. Code is the most reliable documentation.

```
<?php

use Monolog\Logger;
use Monolog\Handler\SwiftMailerHandler;

use Swift_Mailer;
// ... more dependencies you need

// create your Swift_Mailer and Swift_Message instances

$handlers = [
    new SwiftMailerHandler($swiftMailer, $swiftMessage),
    // add more handler you need
];

$log = new Logger('name', $handlers);


$log->warning('Foo');
$log->error('Bar');
```

You have to create a Swift_Mailer and Swift_Message instance for the SwiftMailerHandler. Instead of pushHandler, you can add an array of handlers into the Logger constructor.

The Swift_Message instance is used for every log message where the message replaces every time the mail body.

I can only suggest to you to read the monolog code for information where a further documentation is missing.

Comment: Yesterday, after 2 days of breaking head, i finally got to know how to work with monolog. I've build that Swiftmailer thing & how to log PDO error DB table. Now, i think i've got some grip on it. 

Anyway, thanks for your help & support. I really appreciate that.